# Fill Combobox which is inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

If a `combobox` is inside a `DataTemplate` for the items of an `ItemsControl`.  How can I populate the `combobox` items without hard coding it?  Accessing the `combobox`by it's name from the code-behind is not possible and I would not even like that approach.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="aComboBox" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is there a standard way to populate the `combobox`' values which come from external datastore?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277716/bind-combobox-inside-an-itemscontrol

Comment: would data binding be an option for you? [Data-binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes)

Comment: I was about to give you a quick and clean solution that involved the use of `RelativeSource`, `x:Type` and `FindAncestor`, but it seems that these concepts are utterly absent in winrt. =(

Comment: @ChrisW. That solution works in WPF. Im afraid it will not in WinRT.

Comment: @ChrisW. winrt Xaml is not that powerful in comparison with its wpf counterpart

Comment: @HighCore well crap, I need to find an excuse to get in and learn more of the winrt nuances. :/

Comment: @ChrisW. I wonder if there's a way to have MSFT answer this question. They could also answer what were they thinking when they made this winrt thing =(

Comment: @HighCore Guidance from a MSFT would be great. Especially since getting this working should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly nasty workaround, but have you considered adding a property on the per-item data source that provides the relevant list data? This wouldn't need to duplicate anything - it could refer to the underlying data source, e.g.:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public IList<string> ComboBoxItems { get { return MySource.ItemList; } }
    ...
}
```

You could then bind to this from the `ItemsControl` item template.

This only works if you've got a class whose purpose is to act only as the data source for the items - if you bind directly to underlying model objects, this is less practical. However, it's usually a good idea to add the extra layer (e.g., a ViewModel layer) for various reasons.

Alternatively, could you make the data available through a named resource? You could write `DataContext={StaticResource myData}` which would get you away from the problem of the data context referring to item.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Started watching your Pluralsight course yesterday. It's great! Your first idea was also my first try, but as you said it's quite nasty. Went with the second: <local:MasterData x:Key="masterData" /> ItemsSource="{Binding Hours, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource masterData}}"